# How to fix the problem of mappings when create index？

Tags: java, elasticsearch

When I wanted to create the index in Elasticsearch ,and then use putmappings function to set mappings,I failed and got {"mappings": {}}.And I use the ES6.6.0 and Jest Client.How can I correct my code?

```
//create index
jestResult = client.execute(new CreateIndex.Builder(indexName).settings(settings).build());

mappingsBuild.startObject()
         .startObject(indexName)
         .startObject("properties")                 
         .startObject("content").field("type","text")
         .field("analyzer","ik_smart")
         .field("search_analyzer","ik_max_word").endObject()
         .endObject()
         .endObject();

PutMapping putMapping = new PutMapping.Builder(indexName,typeName,mappings).build();

jestResult = client.execute(putMapping);
```

I expect mappings:

```
"mappings": { 
  "typeName": { 
    "properties": { 
      "content": { 
         "search_analyzer": "ik_smart",
         "analyzer": "ik_max_word",
         "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

is not "mappings":{}

Comment: Is the analyzer "ik_smart" and search_analyzer "ik_max_word" already defined in ES?? I tried with the same mapping and it gave an error saying "analyzer [ik_smart] not found for field [content]"

Comment: Yes,I have installed Ik's plugin, used it in Kibana was worked,and mappings was successful. And I didin't get an error.

Comment: I have known the problems,I should change indexName to typeName in this code:".startObject(indexName)".Thanks for your help.